# Al cargar una imagen en laravel guarda la imagen pero en base de datos crea una dirección temporal

Tags: php, base-de-datos, imagen, laravel-6, laravel-7

Buen dia;

Soy algo nuevo en laravel y me encuentro realizando un proyecto de laravel versión 7, me encuentro con un problema el cual es que al cargar una imagen me crea la imagen en la carpeta public pero en base de datos me crea un dato el cual es tipo "C:\Users\Anderson\AppData\Local\Temp\phpE9D4.tmp" y no el nombre del archivo que se ha personalizado. mi codigo en la parte de store es el siguiente:

```
public function store(StoreModbackupPost $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'BK_Evidencia' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|max:10240'
    ]);
    $filename = "B" . time() . "." . $request->BK_Evidencia->extension();
    $request->BK_Evidencia->move(public_path('images/backupinf'), $filename);
    Modbackup::create($request->validated(), ['BK_Evidencia' => $filename]);
    return back()->with('status','¡Backup creado con éxito!');
}
```

mi funcion store de validación en request es el siguiente:

```
public function rules()
{   
    return [ 
        'BK_Fecha_Ini'=>'required',
        'BK_Fecha_Fin'=>'required',
        'BK_Estado_Id'=>'required',
        'BK_Frecuencia'=>'required',
        'BK_Medida'=>'required',
        'BK_Servidor_Id'=>'required',
        'BK_Tamano'=>'required',
        'BK_Tipo'=>'required',
        'BK_Observacion'=>'required',
        'BK_Usuario'=>'required',
    ];
}
```

actualmente lo realizo por update pero no deberia ser por alli si no directamente en la vista de creación, adjunto el código con el cual si carga la imagen en public y el nombre correcto en base de datos. esta funciona esta cargada en una vista de update la cual carga la imagen a el $id del backup selecionado y se actualiza sin problema.

```
/** 
 * -------------Subir imagen de evidencia de backup.---------------
 */
public function image(Request $request, Modbackup $modbackup, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|max:10240'
    ]);
    $filename = "B" . time() . "." . $request->image->extension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $filename);
    ModbackupImage::create(['image'=> $filename, 'modbackup_id'=> $id]);
    return back()->with('status','¡Imagen cargada con éxito!');
}
```

Agradezco mucho la colaboración prestada.

Quedo inmensamente agradecido.

Comment: Prueba mergeando los arrays para insertar en BD `Modbackup::create( array_merge($request->validated(), ['BK_Evidencia' => $filename]) );`.

Comment: Me ha ayudado a la perfección... ¡Muchas Gracias por la colaboración y el tiempo prestado! :)